# How to register two Adapters for two different Modal classes with HIVE , Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutter-hive

My main.dart file with the error while registering **todosAdapter()**

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final appDocumentDirectory =
      await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  
  Hive.registerAdapter(notesAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(todosAdapter());
 

  await Hive.openBox("notes");
  //await Hive.openBox("todo");

  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => Note_tile(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
    ),
  ));
}
```

My Error while registering **todosAdapter**

*The function 'todosAdapter' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'todosAdapter', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'todosAdapter'.*

My first Modal class is the notes

```
part 'note.g.dart';

var date = new DateTime.now().toString();

var dateParse = DateTime.parse(date);

var formattedDate = "${dateParse.day}-${dateParse.month}-${dateParse.year}";

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class notes {
  @HiveField(0)
  late String title;
  @HiveField(1)
  late String description;
  @HiveField(2)
  late String date = formattedDate;
  notes({required this.title, required this.description});
}
```

the .g.dart file for the note modal class is

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'note.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class notesAdapter extends TypeAdapter<notes> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  notes read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return notes(
      title: fields[0] as String,
      description: fields[1] as String,
    )..date = fields[2] as String;
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, notes obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.title)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.description)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.date);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is notesAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

My Second Modal class is the todos

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'todo.g.dart';

var date = new DateTime.now().toString();

var dateParse = DateTime.parse(date);

var formattedDate = "${dateParse.day}-${dateParse.month}-${dateParse.year}";

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class todos {
  @HiveField(0)
  late String title;
  @HiveField(1)
  late String description;
  @HiveField(2)
  late String date = formattedDate;
  @HiveField(3)
  late bool status = false;
  todos({required this.title, required this.description});
}
```

The .g.dart file of todos class is

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'todo.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class todosAdapter extends TypeAdapter<todos> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  todos read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return todos(
      title: fields[0] as String,
      description: fields[1] as String,
    )
      ..date = fields[2] as String
      ..status = fields[3] as bool;
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, todos obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.title)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.description)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.date)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.status);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is todosAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

Comment: [Hive] tag is already used for Apache Hive - a database on top of Hadoop (Big Data). Please use [flutter-hive] tag for questions like this

Comment: Sure, I will not do that in future...

Answer (score 0):

`Todos` and `Notes` should not have the same `typeId`.try change one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change typeId like this:

todos.dart

`@HiveType(typeId: 1)`

notes.dart

`@HiveType(typeId: 2)`